Concurrency error during parallelized creation of edges from one to many
I am getting the following error when trying to concurrently create a few hundred edges from a given vertex to various other unique vertices.
{
    "requestId": "b90671d4-d8f0-4cca-b0c3-c908ff91d022",
    "code": "ConcurrentModificationException",
    "detailedMessage": "Failed to complete Insert operation for a VertexProperty due to conflicting concurrent operations. Please retry. 0 transactions are currently rolling back.",
    "message": "Failed to complete Insert operation for a VertexProperty due to conflicting concurrent operations. Please retry. 0 transactions are currently rolling back."
}

This is particularly confusing to me, because as far as I can tell, I'm only creating edge properties, and no edge is being modified twice, nor are any two vertices a->b having multiple edges written at once. I'm wondering if it's just a poorly written error message, and that gremlin has some issue with creating many edges from a given vertex AND writing properties to them? The other possibility I can think of is that I'm misunderstanding my query, and I'm actually writing vertex properties and not edge properties, but I tested similar queries and that appears not to be the case.
The code that I'm debugging:
router.post(
  '/users/contacts',
  asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    var successfulPhoneNumbers: string[] = [];
    var failedPhoneNumbers: string[] = [];
    try {
      const g = req.g;

      let { userId, contacts }: { userId: string; contacts: Contact[] } = req.body;

      if (!userId || !contacts) {
        return res.status(400).end('Required userId or contacts not supplied');
      }

      if (contacts.length > 300) {
        return res.status(400).end('Maximum 300 contacts allowed');
      }

      let limit = pLimit(300);

      var now = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();

      // filter out duplicates
      contacts = contacts.filter(
        (contact, index, self) =>
          index === self.findIndex((t) => t.phoneNumber === contact.phoneNumber),
      );

      let contactsPromises = contacts.map(async (contact) => {
        let addContactProperties = (
          query: gremlin.process.GraphTraversal,
        ): gremlin.process.GraphTraversal => {
          query = query.property('createdAt', now);

          if (contact.firstName) {
            query = query.property('firstName', contact.firstName);
          }
          if (contact.lastName) {
            query = query.property('lastName', contact.lastName);
          }
          if (contact.email) {
            query = query.property('email', contact.email);
          }
          if (contact.birthday) {
            query = query.property('birthday', contact.birthday);
          }
          if (contact.address) {
            query = query.property('address', contact.address);
          }

          return query;
        };

        return limit(async () => {
          try {
            let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumber;
            if (!isPhoneNumberValid(phoneNumber)) {
              failedPhoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
              return;
            }

            // if the contact is on the system, add an edge to their user node

            var contactAsUser = await g.V().hasLabel('user').has('phoneNumber', phoneNumber).next();
            var contactAsContact = await g
              .V()
              .hasLabel('contact')
              .has('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
              .next();

            if (!contactAsUser.done) {
              let query = g
                .V(userId)
                .coalesce(
                  __.outE('HAS_CONTACT').where(__.inV().hasId(contactAsUser.value.id)),
                  __.addE('HAS_CONTACT').to(__.V(contactAsUser.value.id)),
                );
              query = addContactProperties(query);
              await query.iterate();
            } else if (!contactAsContact.done) {
              let query = g
                .V(userId)
                .coalesce(
                  __.outE('HAS_CONTACT').where(__.inV().hasId(contactAsContact.value.id)),
                  __.addE('HAS_CONTACT').to(__.V(contactAsContact.value.id)),
                );
              query = addContactProperties(query);
              await query.iterate();
            } else {
              // if the contact is not on the system, add an edge to a new contact node
              let query = g
                .V(userId)
                .coalesce(
                  __.outE('HAS_CONTACT').where(__.inV().has('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)),
                  __.addV('contact')
                    .as('contact')
                    .property(single, 'phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
                    .addE('HAS_CONTACT')
                    .from_(__.V(userId))
                    .to(__.select('contact')),
                );
              query = addContactProperties(query);
              await query.iterate();
            }
            successfulPhoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
          } catch (err: any) {
            console.log(err.toString());
            failedPhoneNumbers.push(contact.phoneNumber);
          }
        });
      });

      await Promise.all(contactsPromises);

      return res.json({
        successfulPhoneNumbers: successfulPhoneNumbers,
        failedPhoneNumbers: failedPhoneNumbers,
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err.message ?? err,
        successfulPhoneNumbers: successfulPhoneNumbers,
        failedPhoneNumbers: failedPhoneNumbers,
      });
    } finally {
      await req.dc.close();
    }
  }),
);



ConcurrentModificationExceptions occur due to deadlocks when two writes are attempting to update quads in the 3 indexes that make up Neptune's storage format.  Most of the time, this occurs due to two quads falling within the same gap in the index and falling prey to conflicting gap locks.  The following doc explains this further:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/transactions-neptune.html#transactions-neptune-conflicts
Most of the time, CMEs are resolved via a 2nd retry.  It is not uncommon to see 2-3% of queries facing CMEs in highly concurrent write workloads on Neptune.

Thanks! I added retry with exponential backoff and it solved the last of my problems.

The issue lay here:
let query = g
                .V(userId)
                .coalesce(
                  __.outE('HAS_CONTACT').where(__.inV().has('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)),
                  __.addV('contact')
                    .as('contact')
                    .property(single, 'phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
                    .addE('HAS_CONTACT')
                    .from_(__.V(userId))
                    .to(__.select('contact')),
                );
              query = addContactProperties(query);
              await query.iterate();

2 problems: first, the coalesce is redundant, leftover from a previous version. Secondly, for some reason, removing g.V(userId).addV().property() cleared up the concurrent errors. Why? Something to do with the behavior of adding a vertex off another vertex perhaps? A minor mystery.
